# How to access UIView title property from another UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to store the title of a view into an NSString but within a class method from one view to be used in another view but I just can't access the title. My code is this:

First view:

```
+(NSString*)title 
{
    NSString * strTitle = self.title;
    return strTitle;
}
```

So, anyone could help me??

Thanks!!! . . .

Comment: Think about it: There are many views in your application. Which title should the class method return?

Comment: @hussainShabbir You have updated what?

Answer (score 2):

You cant access an instance variable from a class method. So you have to change your method as an instance method

```
-(NSString*)title {
     NSString *strTitle = self.title;
     return strTitle;
}
```

Also make sure you set the title for this another viewcontroller before calling this method.
If you want to pass this data to another **UIView** class , then you have to make a title property for this **UIView** class. After initializing the object for this UIView, you can set this title property through this object.

Comment: Ok, I know that, but then how could I pass that data to another UIView?

Comment: Do you want to the title of the screen(First view) to another screen?

Comment: What I need is to get the title from the first view and load it into a tableview cell in another view.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida for this you need to pass the tile into another view through the object of this class. then you can reloadData tableview to refresh the title.

Comment: @manujmv I don't understand this: "...pass the tile into another view through the object of this class." Can you help me with this specific suggestion?

Comment: show me your code for initialing the second view

Comment: @manujmv Right now I am using Charan Giri's suggestion below to init it. But it is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your view's title to viewTitle and get from it.

```
static NSString * viewTitle = nil ;
+ (NSString *)title {
    return viewTitle ;
}
```

Comment: KudoCC I am getting: "Instance variable "viewTitle" accessed in class method. So, not working.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida It builds successfully on my XCode, there must be something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Code to use in secondviewcontroller:

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *titleString;
@end


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize titleString;
```

Code to use in firstviewcontroller:

```
SecondViewController * controllerObj =[[SecondViewController alloc]init];

controllerObj.titleString=NSStringFromClass([self class]);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerObj animated:YES];
```

Comment: Please format your answer correctly.

Comment: Can use the titleString in secondviewcontroller

Comment: Again please format your answer.

Comment: @CharanGiri This code returns me the class name, not the title of the UIView.

Comment: controllerObj.titleString=self.title;

Comment: @CharanGiri controllerObj.titleString=self.title; returns me (null).

Comment: self.title will return string if you set title to navigation bar. if not it will written (null). you can set title as self.title=@"first ViewController";

Answer (score 0):

They are not possible for find name of .xib file name.